# $x'' + x''\cdot x^2 + x'^2 \cdot x + x - k = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$x'' + x'' x^2 + x'^2 x + x - k = 0$ where $k \in \mathbb R$.

Usually, when I come across differential equations like this, I try to solve it through mathematica or some other math tool or find similar equations online. However, these don't help me much in this case (I will admit that I am not very adept with solving second order nonlinear differential equations.) I am wondering if there is really any analytical solution for this differential equation. Note that I am not familiar with how to approach this problem numerically.

Comment: Title and body disagree on some of the levels of differentiation.  Which is correct?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! The title is the correct one. I have now edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x'' + \color{red}{ x''\cdot x^2 + x'^2 \cdot x} + x - k = 0$$
$$x'' + \color{red}{x(x'x)'} + x - k = 0$$
Multiply by $x'$:
$$x'x'' + x'x(x'x)' + xx' - kx' = 0$$
Integrate:
$$x'^2 + (x'x)^2 + x^2 - 2kx = C$$
$$x'^2 (1+ x^2) + x^2 - 2kx = C$$
$$x'^2 =\dfrac  {C -x^2 + 2kx }{1+ x^2}$$
This is separable:
$$\int \sqrt { \dfrac  {1+ x^2}{C -x^2 + 2kx }}dx=\pm t+C_2$$
But as Robert Israel pointed out in his answer the integral is not nice.

Comment: Ok, sorry to bump this once again, but if each term had some arbitrary coefficients, then I assume that this method of "pulling in the derivative" wouldn't work? Is there some way that this could be solved then?

Comment: The coefficients play no role except for the terms in red. You should be able to integrate whatever the coefficients are as long as it is the same DE. The same form I mean. @Physics_Learner

Answer (score 0):

Maple finds an implicit general solution involving an integral:

$$\pm {{\int}}_{}^{x \left(t \right)}\frac{s^{2}+1}{\sqrt{\left(s^{2}+1\right) \left(2 k s -s^{2}+C_1 \right)}}{d}s -t -C_2
 = 0
$$

The integral can be expressed in terms of elliptic integral functions, but it is not pretty.